# JPA how to store newly created tables from some entities in the ADMIN Schema?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, schema

I made a little mistake in one of my projects. I wrongly set JPA to store the newly created tables from the entities in the USER schema.

But now i want to create the tables in the ADMIN schema and not in the USER.
I dropped the tables at USER and selected again the option to create the tables from the entities. The pop up dialog that asked me first time about the schema, does not show up again.
So every time the tables are created, they go to the USER schema.

What should i do to make JPA create the tables in the ADMIN schema?

Where do i find that dialog in Eclipse Helios?

This is my connection pool configuration:

[image]

And this is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="CHAPTER x 12 Container Managed Authentication and Authorization">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/studydb</jta-data-source>     
        <class>entities.User</class>
        <class>entities.Group</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: You need to change the name of the schema to `ADMIN` in the connection settings in the `persistence.xml` file (or in the `connection-pool` setting if you are using JNDI).

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung I just opened my glassfish admin panel to see the connection pool i have configured, but i dont see that option in the connection pool i created. Is it an option i should select, or a new property i should write? What is its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click the tab "Additional Properties".

[image]

**Update:**

Do your entities have something as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "projectcategory", schema = "SCHEMANAME")
```

schema specified.

Comment: I have that already(See my question update), but what i mean is where is the option that says, that the schema where the tables are created is 'ADMIN' and not 'USER'?

Comment: @sfrj: What provider are you using?

Comment: I use the Derby database that comes with glassfissv3 app server

Comment: That worked perfectly, very accurate answer. Thank you very much.